# how can I copy (including all branches) repo to different github account

Tags: git, github

I'm about to clone/copy repo to my new company from old company github account. It's possible to use `fork` function of github? Because I'm afraid that I'm not sure whether my new repo will be also disabled when original repo is disabled by my old company?

Please let me know how to copy/clone repo to another github account including all branches.

Comment: Yes, you are describing a fork. See https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `fork` is the way to copy/clone to another repo, not effect anything even original repo is disabled or deleted?

Comment: Please keep reading the GH docs: https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/